# What's the fastest way to level up new monsties?

Tags: monster-hunter-stories

Throughout the game, you regularly encounter newer and stronger monsters for you to befriend and add to your party. The problem is that they all start at level 1.

Is there a quick way to bring these new monsties up to speed with the rest of your party?

Comment: Logically, you cannot.  Whatever you're doing with the new monster, your existing monster will also get the experience, so they'll always be higher level.

Comment: @Nelson Besides Ratha, who you can't remove from your party until the postgame, you can always swap out other members of your party to stop them from being overlevelled.

Answer (score 2):

High rank barrel cats give a lot of experience and are not difficult to beat. Be sure to use a training charm and go after them. Just one gave me 75000 exp this way.

Comment: Where are high rank barrel cats reliably located?